# How to reset 'schema.rb' to last git head?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql, git-reset

I want to get rid of everything I did since my last commit, including the tables I created, so I did

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -f -d
```

so this got rid of the migrations I created, but in the schema it looks like the tables are still there. I know I can just create new migrations to drop those tables, but I was just wondering for future references how I could reset to the last commit even on the database level.

Another reason why I would need to delete the tables in the database is because when I try to create migrations(models) to create the exact tables, it gives me an error and says they already exist. So if I were to push this to github and production, it would not create the tables since the migrations don't exist. Thus, I think it is necessary for me to delete the created tables locally through some sort (preferably rolling back), and then re-create the migrations.

(I'm using PostGreSQl)

Comment: Presumably your database tables aren't under version control; you'd need to perform the rollback as a separate step, right?

Comment: How would I do this under postgresql?

Comment: I tried doing rake db:rollback, as well as rake db:migrate:down VERSION=xxxxxx, but I don't think its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this temporarily, but probably not the most ideal way to do it.. I just created migrations to remove the tables, ran rake db:migrate, and then deleted the migrations. So this way it's like it never happened.

Comment: Not bad; probably better to run the migrations to undo the changes _before_ resetting the source control, but if you hadn't written those migrations so they could be undone, this might be the best you could do.